# What does the Elder Sign do?

Tags: megami-quest-2

I've purchased several Elder Signs from Acubens Town, and have used them at various locations around the map to no avail. The alt text shown when hovering over the item in-store and in the inventory is simply "???" and using is anywhere seems to result in the "Nothing happened" message. So where am I supposed to use it? What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elder Sign is used to defeat a boss late in the game.

Hint:

> Your quest involving the Elder Sign begins in the Surtr Mountains. Wander there until you find a new item.

Full Spoiler:

> While travelling through the Surtr Mountains, you have a chance to encounter an event that gives you a Mirror of Nitocris. The Mirror of Nitocris reveals Yuggoth Cave. Using the Elder Sign there gives a special message and reduces the boss's defense.